# Apache-Camel console input

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to make a small program that takes in console input such as a user's name, school and other information and then creates a file whose file name is that of the user. Each file will then be located in a folder named after the school. I am not sure how to create a file with those qualities since Camel seems to determine the path and file name before any input is read. Is there a way of getting around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on the file component page like so:

```
// set the output filename using java code logic, notice that this is done by setting
// a special header property of the out exchange
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, "report.txt");
```

you could replace report.txt with the filename you wish to use.

As for the directory, can you not store the directory name in a header and reference it from the endpoint:

```
.to("file://${headers.directory}");
```

more info here: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. The file name portion works correctly. However, I cannot figure out how to get the directory to work. When I try to set the directory it causes an exception. `Dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders is not allowed. Use the fileName option to set the dynamic expression.
 at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:910)`

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Instead of using `to(Endpoint endpoint)` I used `recipientList(simple("${header.directory}"))`